# RegEx with OR not matching first expression

Tags: c#, regex

i'm trying to create a Regular Expression with an Or

i have this

```
(?<data1>a[^b]+b)|(?<data2>^[^b]+b)
```

the goal is to capture everything behind `a` or, when `a` is not present, everything from the start.

```
data = "123412123b" result should be "123412123b"  
data = "123412a123b" result should be "a123b"
```

it always matches the second part of the `or` as it captures to group (data2)
can anyone tell me why this happens

Comment: What is `<data1>` and `<data2>` ?

Comment: Why do you have two different group names (data1 and data2)?  There is no need for two different names.  The group name character should match like using '.  You have < and >.

Comment: @jdweng So i can track which of the parts is executed

Comment: @RemonLucassen: Please accept the answer that worked best for you.

Answer (score 2):

The string is parsed from left to right by default and when the first alternative fails the regex engine tries the second one. The second alternative matches the same text as the first one, so when the string contains `b` after 1 or more chars other than `b`, the second alternative will always win.

You may override the default regex engine behavior in .NET by passing the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` option to make it look for a match in the opposite direction:

```
var pattern = "a[^b]+b|^[^b]+b";
var result = Regex.Match("123412a123b", pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
if (result.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/XzUN1u)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
(?<data>a?[^ab]+b)
```

Comment: Thanx this is te most easy way petty i didn't think of this

Answer (score 0):

you can try below - Easy to understand.

```
var reg = @"(.*)([a].*)";
string data = "123412x123b";
var gps = Regex.Match(data, reg).Groups;

string result = gps.Count > 1 ? gps[2].Value : data;
```